# Volume controls with Apple in-ear headphones

Tags: volume-control, headphones, 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-6p

I want to be able to use the volume controls on a pair of Apple in-ear headphones with my Google Nexus 6P (running Android 6.0). The play/pause function of the middle button works but not the volume +/- .
I understand that there is a difference in the wiring standards between iPhone and other devices for the volume buttons.

**My questions is:**

- Is there any application or software fix for this?
- If no software fix, is there any other solution?

Maybe the easiest solution would be to use a pair of headphones that have the correct wiring, but I did like these Apple headphones.
Thank you for any suggestions or answers on how to possibly solve this.

Comment: Leave it apple to break this kind of thing, right? Apple has proprietary rights over their volume system, so there is no manner of software to fix this. Sorry. (Apple switched the ground and mike too, because that was apparently necessary)

Comment: @EthanZ Out of interest, when you say proprietary rights do you mean that other manufacturers need to pay a license fee for using the Apple system?

Comment: I mean apple has it patented and wont let anyone else use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no software fix because it uses physically different pins on the headphone connector. The hardware simply does not support it. There are plenty of good android compatible headphones out there though.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try search a bit and see if I can find any good Android supported headphones.

Comment: Is there a hardware solution? Pin converter?

Comment: I don't think there are any converters on the market. The standard is digital and patented by Apple so any legal converters would need permission from Apple. Apple has moved on to lightning headphones now, so it is unlikely anyone is ever going to make a product to fill this niche.